# how to pass format to google cloud translation API using the client library?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

We are using [google cloud translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) API in our express application.
I am trying to do translations using the client library instead of making an API request every time. 
1. What I want to know is how to pass the options like format (text or html) to the api while using the client library?
I can achieve this via making http requests using `requestjs` like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2';
var options1 = {
  q: 'amore mio',
  target: 'hi',
  format: 'text',
  source: 'it',
  key: 'my API key'
}

request.post({url:url, qs:options1}, (err, res, body)=> {
  if(err) {
    console.log('ERR: ', err);
  }
  console.log('RES: ', res.statusCode);
  console.log('Body: ', body);
})
```

But the sample for using client library shows only this:

```
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({
  projectId: projectId,
});

// The text to translate
const text = 'Hello, world!';
// The target language
const target = 'ru';

// Translates some text into Russian
translate
  .translate(text, target)
  .then(results => {
    const translation = results[0];

console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);


})
.catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
 });
```

Is there a way I can pass options like 'format' using the client library?

2. How can I pass an array of strings to the q attribute (querystring) of the options object in the first method? If I pass an array directly like:

   `q: ['amore mio', 'grazie']`

I get an error message :

```
RES:  400
Body:  {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Required Text",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Required Text",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to question 2 about passing the array of input arguments, this works fine if you use cURL to send the POST request similar to [this example](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart#make_a_translation_api_request). I have tried it myself with success. I have tried to do different manipulations with your code from snipper 1 with the `request` library, but it seems as if the `request` library is not passing the array correctly. I would generally suggest using the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate_translate_text-nodejs) which can successfully handle arrays in the input text.

Comment: Yes Phil you are right, I have also done this previously via curl and it works but didn't work with request. I am also going with the client library now that I know how to pass the options object, which was the only reason I was even looking at this method. Thanks for the response, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Okay after a little research I just tried to pass options object with format and other properties (like source and target language) instead of target, and it worked. 
So this can be achieved by:

```
const options = {
to: target,
format: 'html',
prettyPrint: true
}

translate
  .translate(text, options)
  .then(results => {
    const translation = results[0];
    console.log('flag: ', Array.isArray(translation));
    console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify

```
`https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=${JSON.stringify([array]}`
```